# How to count query with hint on Spring mongoTemplate?

Tags: spring, mongodb, count, mongotemplate, hint

```java
...
Query query = new Query().addCriteria(...);

query.withHint("Index name");

mongoTemplate.count(query, MyClass.class);
...
```

This count query code doesn't seem to apply hint.

How can I apply index hint to count query on MongoTemplate?